# replace single quotes with double quotes in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, replace, apache-spark-sql

from the below code I am writing a dataframe to csv file.

As my dataframe contains `""` for `None`,  I have added `replace("", None)` because `Null` values are supposed to be represented as `None` instead of `""` (double quotes)

```
newDf.coalesce(1).replace("", None).replace("'", "\"").write.format('csv').option('nullValue', None).option('header', 'true').option('delimiter', '|').mode('overwrite').save(destination_csv)
```

I tried adding `.replace("'", "\"").` but it doesn't work

the data also contains data with single quotes

eg :

```
Survey No. 123, 'Anjanadhri Godowns', CityName
```

I need to replace the single quotes from the dataframe and replace it with double-quotes.

How can it be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace` to replace single quotes with double quotes in all columns before writing the output:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.select([F.regexp_replace(c, "'", '"').alias(c) for c in df.columns])

# then write output
# df2.coalesce(1).write(...)
```

Comment: but this double quotes which I assinged to dataframe will be replaced with None replace `("", None)`  when I write this dataframe to csv @mck

Comment: Why? When you replace `""` you're replacing empty string. It won't replace the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`translate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.translate.html?highlight=translate#pyspark.sql.functions.translate)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

data_list = [(1, "'Name 1'"), (2, "'Name 2' and 'Something'")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data_list, schema = ["ID", "my_col"])
# +---+--------------------+
# | ID|              my_col|
# +---+--------------------+
# |  1|            'Name 1'|
# |  2|'Name 2' and 'Som...|
# +---+--------------------+

df.withColumn('my_col', translate('my_col', "'", '"')).show()
# +---+--------------------+
# | ID|              my_col|
# +---+--------------------+
# |  1|            "Name 1"|
# |  2|"Name 2" and "Som...|
# +---+--------------------+
```

This will replace all occurrences of the single quote character with a double quotation mark in the column `my_col`.